# "it has been three generations since" or "there has been three generations since"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please the difference between the following sentences.

> It has been three generations since we became to use first computers.
>
> There has been three generations since we became to use first computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think both sentences are incorrect mainly due to this phrase: *"since we **became to use first** computers."*

There are a number of ways you could say this. Here are some examples (assuming I correctly understand what you mean):

> *"... since the first computer was invented"*
>
> *"... since we first used computers"*
>
> *"... since we used the **first** computers"* {you will need to define *"first"*}

Note that just saying "first"  may be ambiguous with regards to the classification of the computers (i.e., are you talking about the mechanical,  programmable, or digital computer?)

> *"... since we became the first [generation] to use computers"* {Not sure if this is something we usually say}

---

Getting back to your main question *"It has been"* vs *"There has been"*, your first sentence is correct.

> *"It has been three generations since we ..."*

Here, "has been" works fine because "three generations" is a single time period and is therefore considered singular. *"It has been X years..."* is common usage when we think of those years as a single time period.

Your other sentence

> *"There **has** been three generations since we ..."*

is not common usage {Note that I don't say its incorrect. I am not confident about that claim}. It should be

> *"There **have** been three generations since we ..."*

Because we are using "there" and not "it", we need to use "have" with the plural "three generations". It is easy to explain/understand if we change the sentence a bit:

> *"Three generations **have** passed since we..."* and not *"Three generations **has** passed since we..."*

I personally don't prefer writing *"**There have been three generations** since we..."* in this exact form/construction. I would always go with *"**It has been three generations** since we ..."*. But that is a matter of style and choice, I think.

---

This should be an interesting read: [An arduous ten years have passed.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43607/time-expression-has-have)